# pandas - how to turn multiple column values into rows

Tags: python, pandas

How do you split a row into multiple rows where a single column takes, in turn, the value of a number of columns in the original data frame.

Below I have a DataFrame that 6 columns for banding range (not shown here is 6 other columns for a value for the banding range)

```
            client_guid task_type  banding_1_range  banding_2_range  banding_3_range  banding_4_range  banding_5_range banding_6_range
0                     a  Reactive                0               51              151              351              801            None
1                     b  Reactive                0               51              151              351              801            None
2                     c  Reactive                0               51              151              351              801            None
3                     d  Reactive                0               51              151              351              801            None
4                     e  Reactive                0               51              151              351              801            None
```

I would like to convert the 6 banding range columns into a single column, with a row for each value for the column.

```
           client_guid range_min task_type
0                     a         0  Reactive
1                     a        51  Reactive
2                     a       151  Reactive
...
6                     b         0  Reactive
7                     b        51  Reactive
8                     b       151  Reactive
...
```

I have looked at things like `melt`, `unpivort`, and `unstack` but none have this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `set_idnex` / `stack` :

```
df = df.set_index(['client_guid','task_type']).stack().reset_index(name = 'range_min').drop('level_2', 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   client_guid task_type range_min
0            a  Reactive         0
1            a  Reactive        51
2            a  Reactive       151
3            a  Reactive       351
4            a  Reactive       801
5            a  Reactive      None
6            b  Reactive         0
7            b  Reactive        51
8            b  Reactive       151
9            b  Reactive       351
10           b  Reactive       801
11           b  Reactive      None
12           c  Reactive         0
13           c  Reactive        51
14           c  Reactive       151
15           c  Reactive       351
16           c  Reactive       801
17           c  Reactive      None
18           d  Reactive         0
19           d  Reactive        51
20           d  Reactive       151
21           d  Reactive       351
22           d  Reactive       801
23           d  Reactive      None
24           e  Reactive         0
25           e  Reactive        51
26           e  Reactive       151
27           e  Reactive       351
28           e  Reactive       801
29           e  Reactive      None
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:
Via `melt()`, `drop()` and `sort_values()`:

```
df=(df.melt(['client_guid','task_type'],value_name='range_min')
      .drop('variable',1)
      .sort_values('client_guid',ignore_index=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pd.wide_to_long`

```
out = pd.wide_to_long(df,'banding',i=['client_guid','task_type'],j='drop',suffix='\\w+').reset_index().drop('drop',1)
```